# Boostrap 3 popover dismiss not working as expected in latest version of bootstrap (3.3.5)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to dismiss a bootstrap 3 popover when the user clicks anywhere on the page besides the popover. I found an excellent [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattdlockyer/C5GBU/2/) and added it to a plain html file using the latest version of bootstrap 3 (3.3.5).

In the jsFiddle example everything works as expected because it is using bootstrap version 3.0.2.

**In my application the following happens:**

I click the button to show the popover, I then click outside of the popover to dismiss it. But then when I click the button to show the popover a second time the popover does not open. If I click the button to show the popover again it opens.

Here is everything in the html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="bs-example tooltip-demo">
    <div class="bs-example-tooltips">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-original-title="" title="">Popover on top</button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-original-title="" title="">Popover on bottom</button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-original-title="" title="">Popover on right</button>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's expected that you need to include the popover in document ready because "For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning you must initialize them yourself." Have you considered making the [data-trigger: focus instead of click?](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dismiss-on-next-click) This would likely have your desired result.

Comment: It needs to be click because I am using it as a menu. I just don't understand what in my site could be causing the issue when in the jsFiddle it works fine.

Comment: So it works on fiddle, doesn't work in you project. It means that there is a bug either in your HTML or JS. Can you show your entire HTML document and JS?

Comment: @DanielCook I misunderstood the feature you were telling me to use. It would work but it seems that it only works with anchor tags. My open popover button is an image icon.

Comment: @makshh there isn't much going on. The site is a newly created asp.net webforms application. Im sure the problem comes from one of the pre-installed nuget packages. I am just not sure how to troubleshoot it since there is no JavaScript error in the console. There is no custom JavaScript on the page/site besides what I posted in here.

Comment: Hmmm, I think you have a bug in your JS in the last if statement (you should use `popover` class instead of `danger`.

Comment: I updated it and my code is exactly as it is in jsFiddle and still no luck

Comment: @JTunney For Javascript, showing the ASPX version of the page is not what is needed for diagnosing the issue. You need to load the page in your browser and then View Source and see how imgbtnMenuIcon is being rendered on the page. If you do that, you can also create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Alright, well I just took exactly what was in the jFiddle example and put it in a clean html file and still not working. I updated the code in my post.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is as I cannot reproduce it. But just want to point out that you could use focus as I initially mentioned by adding a tabindex to the image. `TabIndex="[some number]"`

Comment: The reason I don't want to use focus is because when you click on the popover itself it closes. I want the popover to stay open when clicked on. If you have the time please run my updated code in a simple html file on your desktop and you will see the problem.

Comment: Somehow it does not work because you use newest Bootstrap, fiddle you provide in topic uses Bootstrap 3.0.2 and it works.

Comment: @markshh ahh there we go that is exactly he problem. I figured it had to be something of that sort. I just switched the versions in a new jsFiddle and now it fails there too. Now I just need to figure out what the heck could be causing it since I do not want to downgrade my bootstrap version.

Comment: It is related to tooltip code in Bootstrap for sure (I pasted tooltip.js from 3.0.2 to 3.3.5 and it works).

Comment: Yep this is going to be a tough one to figure out. I might just downgrade the js file like you are saying. How would you recommend doing this if I am currently using the full bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js files?

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16732

Comment: Just so everyone knows here is the fix on github: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/17702/files